# No recipient addresses found in header

Tags: php, email

I got this error while sending a mail using PHP mail function

Error Is:- No recipient addresses found in header

Please help me out

Here is the code

//my code starts from here

```
        $to  = navruk@gmail.com;
        $subject  = $_POST['txtsub'];
        $messgae  = $_POST['txtmessage'];
        $signature = $_POST['txtsignature'];
        $redirect = "thanks.php";
        $error    = "error.php";

            $body ="<table width='700' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top'>
                      $messgae <br>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top'>
                      $signature <br>
                </td>  
              </tr>
            </table>";

            $from      = "Aakrutisolutions<info@aakrutisolutions.com>";
            $headers  =  "From: $from\n";
            $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
            $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: Just My Server\r\n";
            $headers .= "".$body."\n";

                    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script language="javascript">
                         location.href='bulkmail.php?sts=mailsent';
                        </script>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script language="javascript">
                         location.href='bulkmail.php?sts=mailnotsent';
                        </script>
                        <?php

                    }
```

//My code ends here

Comment: show us the exact php code you are using

Comment: Um... some code please that we could help you out *with*?

Comment: this is common error in PHP mail, i think every one knows the answer, ok just wait a min i will copy past the code, my code is working in one server, but in godady server it give error.

Comment: @Navruk — If everybody knows the answer, then you must known the answer, therefore you should have no need to ask the question.

Comment: That code does not even parse, it has a syntax error on the first line.

Comment: try to take it +ve, i feel stackoverflow user are more experts that's why i given less description, now i given fill description.

Comment: syntax error, don't you mean: $to  = 'navruk@gmail.com';

Comment: @Navruk Experts are experts because they know what to look for. Experts are not magicians or mind readers.

Comment: oh and use php header(Location ...) not the js

Comment: give me 2 mins i will change my code as per comments then i will let you know

Comment: you must have error checking off which is a real bad idea, otherwise you would of got the error : <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '@' in ...

Answer (score 9):

Your

```
$to  = navruk@gmail.com;
```

assignment needs quotes:

```
$to  = "navruk@gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 8):

I can understand the sarcasm in the comments, never the less, I don't think it is okay to behave like that, even if the answer is obvious. It is very easy to find the information:

```
$headers = 'From: Navruk <navruk@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'To: Navruk1 <navruk@gmail.com>, Navruk2 <navruk@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'Cc: Navruk3 <navruk@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'Bcc: Navruk4 <navruk@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail(
       "navruk@gmail.com",
       "How to do basic mailing",
       "I can easily GOOGLE and find this LINK at the top http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php. Surprisingly, it is the PHP manual. If I CLICK this link I will find not only how to use the PHP command mail, but also a bunch of examples! This took me about 10 seconds to find.",
        $headers
      );
```

I suggest you read the message and try it yourself, can you beat my 10 seconds?!?

Comment: And your answer is less sarcastic than the comments how...? ;o)

Comment: Hehe, Sarcasm with a touch of finesse :D Anyway, Eugene Mayevski made us all look like idiots, touché!

Comment: +1 for the consideration with the guy. People does not need to be rude to others only because they are smarter, stronger or rich... Good guy greg attack =)